# Has there been a project to apply machine learning to generation of indices for books?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

Generating an index for a textbook is a tedious task. Can one automate it with machine learning? Are there any references to previous attempts in the literature to do this?

Comment: I have not seen this idea before, but it sounds like it'd be interesting. Do it!

Comment: C.f. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/856/is-there-an-automatic-process-to-create-index-creation

Answer (score 3):

To add on to the answer by @denis-tarasov, I would refer you to [this amazing article](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2017/mar/30/in-our-google-era-indexers-are-the-unsung-heroes-of-the-publishing-world) by the Guardian.

Take a look at this passage:

> One of the things that’s commonly imagined is that indexing is, in the age of Google, something that can be outsourced to a computer algorithm. Dead wrong. A concordance – essentially, an alphabetical list of all the words in a book with page references – can be done by a computer. But an index, to be useful, needs to be done by a human. In a book about the Middle East, say, an entry that said: “Syria 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 23, 25, 26, 27 … ” would be no use at all.

Indeed, the main argument is that keyword/keyphrase extraction cannot replace the human element of wittiness, critical thinking, and engagement with the reader of a book.

Comment: I agree that AI can't yet match human level of insight. However, example of "Syria 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 23, 25, 26, 27 …" is to naive. No modern (or even good 15 years old) keyword extraction method can make such a mistake. Even simple Inverse Document Frequency weighting over pages/paragraphs will probably be enough to avoid  it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is very similar to keywords/keyphrases extraction problem. Keywords extraction is well studied task (see for example [this paper](http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~saidul/acl14.pdf) for review). Possible approaches include  heuristics, supervised machine learning (with a number of special feautures like TD/IDF, position in the sentence and other) and  language models. Powerful keywords/keyphrases extraction tools exist, thus one can try them first, and see if they do job well.